# Colorbar shinks scatter plot

Tags: matplotlib, shrink, colorbar

Hopefully a simple fix.. I have a colorbar plotted to the right of my image.  Doing so shrinks my scatter plot to the left; however, I would like to keep the scatter as close to 1:1 as possible as the x- and y-axis are at the same scale.

Comment: use `ax.set_aspect('equal')` which will force the ratio between x and y to be 1:1 independent of the axis shape.  The re-sizing in un-avoidable, the color bar needs to be fit in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

which will force the ratio between the x-units (data-units/screen-units) and y-units to be 1:1 independent of the axis shape. The re-sizing in un-avoidable, the color bar needs to be fit in there.